# Array subset of another array descending order binary search. Here's my code. It always prints "false"

Tags: arrays, boolean, binary-search

this is the boolean method I need

```
public static boolean isSubsetOf(int a[], int b[]){

for (int i=0;i<b.length;i++){
    if (binarySearch(a,0 ,a.length-1, b[i])==false) return false;
}
return true;
}
```

and this is the binary search for descending order

```
private static boolean binarySearch(int[] a, int i, int j, int k) {
int mid;
if (i<=j){
    mid=(i+j)/2;
    if (a[mid]==k) return true;
    else if (a[mid]<k) binarySearch(a, i,j=mid-1, k);
    else binarySearch(a,i=mid+1,j,k);
}
return false;
}
}
```

Comment: Try debug statements. Print the values of a, i, j, mid to the System.out.println at some point in your binarySearch loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were ignoring the return values of the recursive `binarySearch` calls.

Here's a corrected version [please pardon the gratuitous style cleanup]:

```
private static boolean
binarySearch(int[]a, int i, int j, int k)
{
    int mid;
    boolean match;

    if (i <= j) {
        mid = (i + j) / 2;

        if (a[mid] == k)
            return true;

        if (a[mid] < k)
            match = binarySearch(a, i, j = mid - 1, k));
        else
            match = binarySearch(a, i = mid + 1, j, k);
        if (match)
            return match;
    }

    return false;
}
```

But, binary search can often be done [faster] *without* recursion:

```
private static boolean
binarySearch(int[]a, int i, int j, int k)
{
    int mid;

    while (i <= j) {
        mid = (i + j) / 2;

        if (a[mid] == k)
            return true;

        if (a[mid] < k)
            j = mid - 1;
        else
            i = mid + 1;
    }

    return false;
}
```